# Objective C, What is this warning?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

> `void _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool)`, `0x4c60190`: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. `UIKit` should not be called from a secondary thread.

I get this warning message if I try to get text from a `UITextView`.

Comment: Posting the relevant code would be a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you spawn another thread and call UIKit method from in it? Methods like `+ (void)detachNewThreadSelector:(SEL)aSelector toTarget:(id)aTarget withObject:(id)anArgument` or `- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg`
 will spawn a new thread.

UI related codes should be used only in main thread. Because many of UI code uses multithreading heavily, so allowing of calling UI code from any thread easily cause unmanageable deadlock. So most of UI frameworks have this rule.

You can force a code to run in main thread by using method like `- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait`

As an example,

```
- (void)UIControlCode
{
}
- (void)processingCodeInOtherThread
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(UIControlCode) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fixed the problem. The problem was I was trying to access UITextview from another thread not from the main thread.